# Non persistent keyboard shortcuts in Unity

Tags: unity, 12.10, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System shortcut setting is always restored to default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204843/system-shortcut-setting-is-always-restored-to-default)

I did change the keyboard shortcuts for window navigation in Unity to use hjkl (vim movement). I did reassign the shortcuts via GUI in *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts*.

Here are two examples of the assigned shortcuts:

- Move window one workspace to the left = <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Switch to workspace left = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Occasionally, when restarting the maching, these shortcuts are being reset to theit default values:

- Move window one workspace to the left = <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
- Switch to workspace left = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>

**How can I make these changes permanent?** Can someone help me, narrowing down the problem?

Comment: Did you upgrade from 12.04? Because I've seen another user ask a [similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204843/system-shortcut-setting-is-always-restored-to-default) so I'm wondering whether it affects only some people who upgrade or whether it's a fresh install issue.

Comment: Yes, indeed I did an upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. Filed a bug report already: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-indicator-mods/+bug/1074426

Comment: excellent, I'm hit by the same. thanks for the link to the bug report, shvnrrthn!